# How to send events to RichTextBox from a wrapper class?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

## Background

I'm building a C# application using a library that cannot display Windows Forms elements directly.

When I wanted to display and edit rich text I decided to build a wrapper class for `RichTextBox` so that it could handle all the heavy lifting re layout & storing styles and my class would simply handle displaying them in the new library.

### Current Architecture

Currently there are 3 classes that matter to this problem:

- `RichTextBox` - the .Net `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox` control, should handle most of the logic, cannot be displayed directly
- `Model` - A subclass of `RichTextBox` designed to expose handles to `StyledText` to help it display things properly
- `PStyledText` - Designed to display the data stored in `RichTextBox`, has `Model` as a field. All events must go through `PStyledText`

## The Problem

Until now I've handled all the text entry using my wrapper class. This is unwieldy, increasingly complicated, and clearly duplicating effort - the `RichTextBox` class itself was built to handle this kind of input, and will do it better than I can.

Therefore, I need some way of sending all keyboard events fired on my wrapper class to be sent to the `RichTextBox`. How do I do this?

## Code

### Model

```
/// <summary>
/// A utitlity class to look act as the Owner for the document
/// </summary>
public class Model : RichTextBox
{
    #region Fields
    /// <summary>
    /// The PStyledText this class is acting as a Owner for
    /// </summary>
    public PStyledText Subject { get; protected set; }


    #endregion Fields

    #region Constructors
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a Model to serve a PStyledText
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target">The PStyledText this is the Owner for</param>
    public Model(PStyledText target)
        : base()
    {
        Subject = target;
        CurIndex = 0;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Events

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a key is depressed while the attatchedPStyledText has keyboardFocus
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">The event describing the keydown</param>
    public void OnKeyDown(PInputEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(new KeyEventArgs(e.KeyData));
    }

    public void OnKeyPress(PInputEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(new KeyPressEventArgs(e.KeyChar));
    }

    public void OnKeyUp(PInputEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyUp(new KeyEventArgs(e.KeyData));
    }
    #endregion events


}
```

### PStyledText

```
/// <summary>
/// A class to provide rich text with editing capabilities
/// </summary>
public class PStyledText : PNode
{
    #region Fields
    /// <summary>
    /// Model is an extention of RichTextBox, providing the logic for the class. 
    /// Because it has some major differences to Java's Document class, 
    /// many of the details of the implementation differ from the Java version
    /// </summary>
    public Model Document
    {
        get
        {
            return document;
        }
        protected set
        {
            document = value;
        }
    }

    private Model document;


    #endregion Fields

    #region Constructors
    /// <summary>
    /// Create an empty PStyledText object
    /// </summary>
    public PStyledText()
        : this("")
    { }


    /// <summary>
    /// Create a PStyledText object with set text
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">The text to fill the object with</param>
    public PStyledText(String text)
    {
        Document = new Model(this);


        DefaultHandler = new TextEntryInputHandler(this);
        AddInputEventListener(DefaultHandler);

        AddInputEventListener(new PStyledTextSelectEventHandler());



    }
    #endregion Constructors

    #region Methods



    public override void OnClick(PInputEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
        Document.OnClick(e);
        UpdateCarat();
    }
}

public class TextEntryInputHandler : PBasicInputEventHandler
{
    public PStyledText Owner { get; protected set; }

    public TextEntryInputHandler(PStyledText o)
    {
        Owner = o;
    }

    public override void OnKeyDown(object sender, PInputEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(sender, e);
        Owner.Document.OnKeyDown(e);
        Owner.UpdateCarat();
    }

    public override void OnKeyPress(object sender, PInputEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(sender, e);
        Owner.Document.OnKeyPress(e);
        Owner.UpdateCarat();
    }

    public override void OnKeyUp(object sender, PInputEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyUp(sender, e);
        Owner.Document.OnKeyUp(e);
        Owner.UpdateCarat();
    }

    #endregion

}
```

[Full code available](https://github.com/malacandrian/Piccolo.NET) on GitHub

Comment: Show us what code you have that's relevant

Comment: There is a [Windows Forms `RichTextBox` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a [WPF `RichTextBox` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Please indicate the UI toolkit you are using in the tags.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Not sure what the hangup might be.  You certainly ought to be *overriding* the OnKeyDown and OnKeyPress methods, not hiding them.  Call base.OnKeyXxx() to get the event fired.

Comment: @HansPassant - I'm not overriding because the library passes its own class (`PInputEventArgs`) to events, so `RichTextBox` doesn't have an appropriate method to override. 

That said, I've added the `base.OnKeyXxx()` methods, and removed my own way of handling input (see updated code) and it still doesn't seem to be doing anything.